# More easly? One search for str_replace. One command more find?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of any other method where you can modify multiple items with one search? For example.

```
$email->body = str_replace({{fName}}, $user->f_name, $email->body);
$email->body = str_replace({{lName}}, $user->l_name, $email->body);
$email->body = str_replace({{email}}, $user->email, $email->body);
```

Do this here with three commands, lots of resources. Is there a better solution to it?

Comment: [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accepts arrays for the first two parameters

Comment: And you can also use `strtr()` , which accepts an associative array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
str_replace(
    ['{{fName}}', '{{lName}}', '{{email}}'], 
    [$user->f_name, $user->l_name, $user->email],
    $email->body
);
```

Comment: This format faster for program runing?
str_replace(
    ['{{fName}}', '{{lName}}', '{{email}}'], 
    [$user->f_name, $user->l_name, $user->email],
    $email->body
);

like this?

$email->body = str_replace({{fName}}, $user->f_name, $email->body);
$email->body = str_replace({{lName}}, $user->l_name, $email->body);
$email->body = str_replace({{email}}, $user->email, $email->body);

Comment: This format is more readable and less cluttered. What about performance, I think that it will be slightly faster because of one function call instead of three, but anyway the boost will not be large. If you want you can do a benchmark, but I offer you not to be bothered by such a little performance differences.